# WCF: How to stop myServiceHost.Close() from disposing of myServiceHost object?

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-studio-2010, garbage-collection, servicehost

Apparently Close and Dispose are effectively the same. I want to be able to Close and Open my ServiceHost instance without having to reinstantiate it everytime. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: or to rephrase the question - how can I "disable" myServiceHost without calling Close?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[ServiceHost.Close](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicehost.close.aspx) is effectively identical to `Dispose()`.  This is true, in general, with all types that have a `Close()` method - `Dispose()` is implemented in terms of `Close()`.

FYI - `ServiceHostBase` implements `Dispose()` explicitly via:

```
void IDisposable.Dispose()
{
    base.Close();
}
```

This, effectively, means that when you close the ServiceHost, you'll always Dispose() of it.  There is no supported way to "reopen" it without recreating it.

Comment: @Reed Copsey, thanks for your response. Let me rephrase the question, can I "disable" the serviceHost object without calling Close?

Comment: @Sam: Nope.  Close it, and recreate it when you want to "enable" it again.

Comment: Why do you want to "disable" the serviceHost?  The service should always be available to its callers.

Comment: @Richard, I'm testing my WCF service being hosted in a WinForms app.. and more specifically, I just want to be able to minimise unnecessary memory re-allocation. I'm coming from a Delphi background so I want more control of my objects ;-)

Comment: @Sam: Get out of that habit.  You'll find that thinking that way actually, when you're all said and done, hurts you more than helps.  Allocations in C# are cheap - unlike native code - it's often faster to let the object get collected and reallocate than it is to try to prevent it, especially if its not long lived...

Comment: @Reed, deallocating memory and re-allocating it again can be faster than checking a boolean flag and going down a tree branch that's got half the instructions of the usual dispose/recreate routine? are you serious? Maybe if the code was being interprited line by line everytime it was executed! Don't tell me that's what's happening.

Comment: @Sam: Depends on what you're doing.  If there was a simple "IsEnabled" property, then of course not.  However, you'd be surprised - I've found that doing things I used to think of as required (ie: lifting allocations out of loops) will often slow down a C# program instead of improving them...