# How can I stop reply from WCF service WebServiceHost

Tags: .net, wcf, webservicehost

I have a WCF WebServiceHost with WebHttpBinding.

I don't want to reply to IPs that are not whitelisted to hide the presence of the service, rather than answering with a 404 error.

I have tried without success:

```
OperationContext.Current.Channel.Close() / Abort()

Throw New InvalidOperationException()

Kill the thread but no new connection can be established
```

My service behavior is set to

```
InstanceContextMode.PerSession
ConcurrencyMode.Single
```

Any idea?

Comment: Maybe you can try using `ServiceHost.Close()`, you can check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4964161/wcf-how-to-stop-myservicehost-close-from-disposing-of-myservicehost-object

Comment: Or the client should close the service channel https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8492469/wcf-callback-interface-who-closes-the-channel.

Comment: Thanks for your ideas but they are not applicable. I can't stop the service because it has to accept other connections with white IPs. And I don't have access to the client side because it is a web browser.
For the moment I answer with HTTP error 418 I'm a teapot

Comment: For "HTTP error 418 I'm a teapot" you can check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52340027/is-418-im-a-teapot-really-an-http-response-code).